# HAProxy + Node.js & Express not forwarding IP address

Tags: node.js, haproxy

I'm trying to get HAProxy to pass the user's IP address by using:

```
option forwardfor
```

In my haproxy.cnf

But for some reason my express returns no IP address. This is the code I'm using in Node.js:

```
    var usrIP = "0";
    if( req.connection.remoteAddress !== null || req.connection.remoteAddress !== "null" || req.connection.remoteAddress.length > 1 ) {
        usrIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    }
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get client IP in headers.

"forwardfor" option which will add an "X-Forwarded-For" header with the
   original client's IP address. You must also use "httpclose" to ensure
   that you will rewrite every requests and not only the first one of each
   session :

```
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
```

Line 122 http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.2/doc/architecture.txt

Comment: Still get the same error when trying to read `req.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: This solved it! `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` Thanks a bunch for the help

Comment: `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` solved the problem for me as well after implementing

`option httpclose
option forwardfor`

in haproxy